# Update countdown variable on Angular Timer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, countdowntimer

I am using Angular Timer http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer

But I can't update the countdown variable. I see that I'm not the only one having this issue. I tried some "solutions" but this didn't work. What is the best way to make it work? Don't want to make a new countdown because this timer directive has a lot of features that I need. It's just that I can't update the countdown from a controller.

I have a select updating content which works perfect, except for the timer, I've added different time values

```
$scope.typeWods = [
    { label: 'EMOM',        value: 1,   time: 500    },
    { label: 'TABATA',      value: 2,   time: 900    },
    { label: 'POR VUELTAS', value: 3,   time: 800    },
    { label: 'AMRAP',       value: 4,   time: 1200   },
    { label: '21-15-9',     value: 5,   time: 700    }
];
```

The variable is updated, but the countdown property is not. Any good solution out there? Don't know what else to try.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/YDwnS5gOoQC2YppoxWq5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i resolved this with **Vinay K** answer but instead of using `timer-set-countdown` i used `timer-set-countdown-seconds` to update the countdown and work perfect!

```
$scope.$broadcast('timer-set-countdown-seconds', $scope.variable);

$scope.$on('timer-set-countdown-seconds', function (e, seconds) {
    console.log(seconds);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`angular-timer` requires `momentjs` and `humanize-duration` libraries.

This is mentioned at - https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer#requirements

Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OkqS8fyZCiegsUjIW13L?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, didn't understand why the plnkr doesn't work. But the real question is how to update the countdown variable, still not working.

Comment: @aluknot, please check the updated plnkr. We need to broadcast `timer-set-countdown` to update the countdown.

Comment: Thanks Vinay K. Now the plnkr work perfect but dunno why is not working on me. I had errors with `humanize-duration` but now i installed and updated the angular-timer librarie and other libraries too, i don't get errors now but is not working the change... `$scope.$broadcast('timer-set-countdown', 50);` is not executed. Is an ionic/cordova project